# LinkObjects property gets emptied when print occurs before save to Realm database

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I think I stumbled upon some undefined behavior in RealmSwift.

The "backReferences" property in Dog class is defined so:

```
let backReferences = LinkingObjects(fromType: Person.self, property: "dogs")
```

I create two objects, where person in parent to the dog:

```
self.realm = try! Realm()

let person = Person()
person.firstName = "Paul"
person.secondName = "Brewczynski"

let dog = Dog()
dog.name = "MyDogName"

person.dogs.append(dog) // Right now this dog is mine
```

Then:

```
//print("BackReferebces print #0  - on yet unmanaged realm Object")
//print(dog.backReferences)
try! realm!.write {
    realm?.add(person) // Writing person to db, with dog reference
    print("BackReferences print #1")
    print(dog.backReferences)
}

print("BackReferences print #2")
print("Show backReferences in using my orginal reference to dog \(dog.backReferences)")
print("BackReferences print #3")
print("Show backReferences using Persons's reference \(person.dogs.first!.backReferences)")
```

It works perfectly (prints correctly backreference to Person holding dog) until you uncomment 2 first lines, and print dog's backReference before it is managed by Realm.

Then in print #1 and #2 I get empty list:

```
BackReferences print #1
LinkingObjects<> <0x7fa0d1611c00> (

)
BackReferences print #2
Show backReferences in using my orginal reference to dog LinkingObjects<> <0x7fa0d1611c00> (

)
```

Why is so? Have I stumbled on some Realm's undefined behavior?

Whole AppDelegate file:

https://gist.github.com/pbrewczynski/8ebc3cb5796850008a90f79dbee6bd04

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the expected behaviour. Even though this is not exactly documented anywhere, in [this](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4195) GitHub issue a Realm engineer mentions that

> `LinkingObjects` always returns an empty collection for unmanaged objects.

The only hint to this I could find in [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/LinkingObjects.html) is the sentence

> `LinkingObjects` always reflects the current state of the Realm on the current thread,

however, this isn't really explicit about the fact that only managed objects are part of `Realm`, so an unmanaged object cannot be part of the state of the `Realm` on the current thread.

All in all, you always need to persist objects in `Realm`, before their `LinkingObjects` properties would work as expected.